# Replacing multiple strings in Outlook email body with Hyperlinks using RegEx

Tags: regex, vbscript, hyperlink, outlook, rules

When an email comes in with a body that contains any string of 5 numbers, I want to replace that with a URL in order to create a clickable link to the record. See code below:

I have 2 problems.

1. With the code below, I'm only getting one string replaced in each email that comes in. So, If I had a set of 4 five number ID's, only one would be converted into a Hyperlink.
2. The script seems to ruin all formatting of the incoming email. Ideally, all I want to change is the 5 number string into a hyperlink, the rest of the formatting should stay the same, with zero line breaks or carriage returns, etc...

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub InsertHyperLink(MyMail As MailItem)
       Dim body As String, re As Object, match As Variant, slgLink As String
       body = MyMail.body
       slgLink = "http://lnet/servicelog/serviceLogInfo.jsf?slNumber="

       Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
       re.Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

       For Each match In re.Execute(body)
           body = Replace(body, match.Value, "<p><a href=" & Chr(34) & slgLink & Right(match.Value, 5) & Chr(34) & ">" & Right(match.Value, 5) & "</a></p>", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
       Next

       MyMail.HTMLBody = body
       MyMail.Save
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading plain text Body property, but you are setting HTMLBody. Read the HTMLBody instead.

Comment: That fixes the formatting issue, thank you! Any ideas on why it's not looping properly?

Comment: I don't know about regex, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with some help from [\u\pmo86](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/4bxxyv/replacing_multiple_strings_in_outlook_email_body/d1degw1?context=3), here's the correct way to do it (much more elegant):

```
Sub InsertHyperLink(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim slgLink As String, re As Object
    slgLink = "<a href=""http://lnet/servicelog/serviceLogInfo.jsf?slNumber=$1"">$1</a>"

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "(\b(\d{5})\b)"
    re.Global = True

    MyMail.HTMLbody = re.Replace(MyMail.HTMLbody, slgLink)
    MyMail.Save
    Set re = Nothing
End Sub
```

As you can see in the example, it's using built in functions to backreference $1 which is referencing the match directly.

Comment: I'm trying this piece of code, but how do I actually make Outlook apply this to every e-mail?